# Google cloud storage gsutil tool with Java

Tags: google-cloud-storage

If we have around 30G files (ranged from 50MB to 4GB) need to be uploaded to Google Cloud Storage everyday, according to google docs, gsutil might be the only fitted choice, isn't it?

I want to call gsutil command by Java, now the code below can work. But If I delete that while loop, the program will stop immediately after the runtime.exec(command) but python process was started but doing no uploading and it will soon be killed. I wonder why.

The reason I read from sterr stream is inspired by [Pipe gsutil output to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823714/pipe-gsutil-output-to-file)

I decide whether gsutil finish executing by read util the last line of its status output, but is it a reliable way? Is there any better ways to detect whether gsutil execution is end in Java?

```
String command="python c:/gsutil/gsutil.py cp C:/SFC_Data/gps.txt"
            + " gs://getest/gps.txt";
 try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        System.out.println("the output stream is "+process.getErrorStream());
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream())); 
        String s; 
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println("The inout stream is " + s);
        }                
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

There are certainly more than one way to upload 30G worth of data per day to GCS. Since you are working in Java, have you considered to use the Cloud Storage API Java client library?
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/storage/v1

As for the specific questions about calling gsutil from Java using Runtime.exec(), I suspect when there is no while loop, the program will exit immediately after creating the sub-process, causing the "process" variable to be GC'ed, which might kill the sub-process.

I think you should wait for the sub-process to complete, which is effectively what the while loop is doing. Or you can just call waitFor() and check the existValue() if you don't care about the output:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: Ha, I'm confused. Earlier I found this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/ , also called GCS Java API in which The Files API feature is to be abandoned. So I followed that page ended up finding "GCS Client Library" and got sample code which is a web app. I tried it, uploading a 4GB file took around 20 minutes versus 5 minutes by gsutil. This one you sent is used for Java application instead of a web app. For now, it is what I want for now. Thanks so much. I'll definitely try on it.

Comment: But, still don't get what's the essential difference between  these two "Client Library" for Java...

Comment: And, did you find anything on resumable uploading around this API? I only found around RESTful API used by web app I think

Comment: As for runtime.exec(). It says "The subprocess is not killed when there are no more references to the Process object, but rather the subprocess continues executing asynchronously." It somehow can explain what I observed later when I use -m in that command that two python processes kept running. But still cannot explain why those two python processes running without doing any uploading...(network consumption is 0 in task manager)

Comment: I agree the names are very confusing, and I will try my best to explain the differences.

Comment: The "Cloud Storage API Client Library (for Java)" I mentioned is part of the "Google APIs Client Library" and provides full functionality for accessing GCS. You can think of it as parallel to the GCS REST API but conforms to the same standard as other Google APIs.

Comment: Both "Google Cloud Storage Java API" (Files API) and "Google Cloud Storage Java Client Library" mentioned in your earlier comment are specific to AppEngine. The former is part of the AppEngine SDK as is already deprecated. The latter is a separate client library that needs to be downloaded and deployed with your app, which basically wraps the GCS REST API and provides a simpler interface and some performance tuning.

Comment: It's a very good explanation, get much clear now. So, as for files of large size, the "AppEngine" side of interfaces doesn't as fit as the other side(the one you mentioned). Is that correct? Is the main cause of this difference the limit of web browser?

Comment: I don't have the exact numbers, but I think the performance of the AppEngine specific client library (the REST API wrapper) and the Google APIs client library should be comparable in performance, so you can choose to use either one as long as it provides the functionality you need. gsutil does provide some nice functionality for uploading large files, including resumable/parallel upload, exponential backoff on errors, etc. So it is a good option if you can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I draw the following pic according to Zhihong Yao's explanation. Hope it can help anyone with the same question as mine.

[image]