# Accessing google play store data using GSUTIL on nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, spawn, gsutil

I am trying to access data from google play store using GSUTIL in nodejs.

when I run the following command on my command line, I am able to get the files:
gsutil cp -r gs://mybucket /mylocalmachine

How do I run this command on my node server to get the same result? The below code doesnot yield any result

var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function copyUsingGSUTIL() {

```
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    var child = exec("gsutil cp -r", ["gs://mybucket", "mylocalmachine"],{cwd:"/Applications/gsutil"});
     console.log(child)

     child.on('close', function (code) {
         console.log('Exit code' + code);

     });
 });
```

}

Answer (score 1):

*gsutil* is a python program so you have to invoke `python` and use the full paths in the exec command like

```
String command = "python c:/gsutil/gsutil.py  cp -r gs://mybucket/mylocalmachine" + "C:/your absolute path here/Applications/gsutil";
...
...
var child = exec(command);
 console.log(child);
...
...
```

There is also a java alternative for gsutil see this https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/storage/v1

**See also this thread [Google cloud storage gsutil tool with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889376/google-cloud-storage-gsutil-tool-with-java)**

Comment: If they're using Node anyway, I might suggest the gcloud-node library: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node

Comment: To use gcloud-node library, I will need to enable billing, which is not an option at the moment.