# firebase gustil cp command output, can not store in txt file. how get generation of new version?

Tags: firebase, version-control, firebase-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-shell

I need output of "gsutil cp" command to output.txt file.
using ">" symbol its just printing on terminal, but not writing to output.txt

1. How can I do it? As it is taking few seconds to execute, I don't know about to deal asynchronous commands output.
2. If any body know, how to get generation of file after success of "cp"?
   I know how to display on terminal (using -v option in cp command). But I need only generation, as it is printing so many lines in output.

Comment: I found what I think it is a related case here in Stack Overflow, maybe it is useful in your case. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823714/pipe-gsutil-output-to-file). I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you @Vicky. I will consider solution of given link. I need to extract size and generation from link. One another approach I find is using "gustil du object-link" command. It will give me output as "size_in_byte  object-link#generation". Then I have to use "cut" command to extract  "size_in_byte" and "#generation".

Comment: sorry to say but "-L" option gives destination URL without new generation number. I can get file size from output.

Comment: I think that I have find a possible explanation about why the "-L" isn't working as expected, in this related [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823714/pipe-gsutil-output-to-file/16824448#16824448) is said that the "-L" command only works saving the purpose of the command your are using, so maybe it is not saving the correct data because the output of the used commands doesn't get the data you need. Please check it, maybe it helps you to find a way to get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation states [1], the gsutil cp command allows you to copy data between your local file system and the cloud, within the cloud, and between cloud storage providers.

If you want to save the output of a gsutil cp command to a text file, here is an example:

`gsutil cp your-file-here gs://your-bucket-here 2> result.txt`

Using a file called hello.txt and one of my buckets, the content of result.txt is

```
Copying file://hello.txt [Content-Type=text/plain]...
/ [1 files][   92.0 B/   92.0 B]
Operation completed over 1 objects/92.0 B.
```

[1] - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp

Comment: got the output in file properly. But it's difficult to get generation and size from this output. Its giving file size output in MB I need in bytes. I have to work on script that will give generation and file size in bytes